# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'options')" but select menu options are not null

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror

The following JS function is supposed to assign the value from the chosen drop-down menu to the variable "menuItem" and reset the other three menus when the user changes one of the menus.

However, [when I run it in CodePen][1], I keep getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'options')
> at [… line] 3

I looked up what that error means, and understood it to mean an option in a select menu has no value. But all the options in the test menus have values.

Can someone explain (without getting too technical) why the error is happening, and suggest a fix?

```html
<label for="label">Select a menu item:</label>
<select id="MenuOne" class="TestMenu" onchange="setMenuValue(MenuOne)">
  <option selected value="9999">Numbers</option>
  <option value="one">One</option>
  <option value="two">Two</option>
  <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
<select id="MenuTwo" class="TestMenu" onchange="setMenuValue(MenuTwo)">
  <option selected value="9999">Phonetics</option>
  <option value="alpha">Alpha</option>
  <option value="bravo">Bravo</option>
  <option value="charlie">Charlie</option>
</select>
<select id="MenuThree" class="TestMenu" onchange="setMenuValue(MenuThree)">
  <option selected value="9999">RGB</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>
<select id="MenuFour" class="TestMenu" onchange="setMenuValue(MenuFour)">
  <option selected value="9999">Pets</option>
  <option value="cat">Cat</option>
  <option value="dog">Dog</option>
  <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
</select>
<div id="label"></div>
```

```js
function setMenuValue(menuId) {
  // Get the selected option from the menu.
  var selectedOption = document.getElementById(menuId).options[
    document.getElementById(menuId).selectedIndex
  ];

  // Set the value of the "menuItem" variable to the value of the selected option.
  var menuItem = selectedOption.value;

}

  [1]: https://codepen.io/rcosgrove/pen/yLRPpKN
```

Comment: Your function accepts a string, so add quotes when you call it : `setMenuValue('MenuOne')`

Comment: Although I could rewrite your javascript, the problem that you are having is most likely because of this **setMenuValue(MenuTwo)** MenuTwo isn't a declared variable, so it can't be used. Just wrap them in single quotes **setMenuValue('MenuTwo')**

Comment: why using this code? `var selectedOption = document.getElementById(menuId).options[]` if you want the value of the selectd option just use an eventListener to get that value

Comment: Chris G: I prefer calling the function via onchange here. May not be "good" compared to using an eventListener, but I find it easier to keep track of which function is doing what.

Comment: If you fix both errors, the first one with the setMenuValue('MenuOne') missing the quotes and the second one in my answer the code will still not work. The for loop is basically wrong, you need to loop through all of the menus. And the one currently only resets the first 3 menus regardless of whether they were the menu that changed or not. The event approach is a better option

Comment: user15367692 – I realise the loop is broken. But I'm going to take a different (and simplier) approach for that part of the script.

Comment: For anyone reading these comments in the future, these comments refer to broken code that came after "var menuItem = selectedOption.value;", which I've removed from this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of sending the id as a string in each function, just send the event like this `onchange="setMenuValue(this)"` then you can access whichever value and id you just sent depending on what you selected. Just check this working example.

Note: This example only addresses part of the issue

```js
function setMenuValue(e) {
  // Get the selected option from the menu.
  var selectedOption = e.value;
  console.log("selected value= " + selectedOption);
  console.log("selected id= " + e.id);

  // Set the value of the "menuItem" variable to the value of the selected option.
  var menuItem = selectedOption;
}
```

```html
<label for="label">Select a menu item:</label>
<select id="MenuOne" class="TestMenu" onchange="setMenuValue(this)">
  <option selected value="9999">Numbers</option>
  <option value="one">One</option>
  <option value="two">Two</option>
  <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
<select id="MenuTwo" class="TestMenu" onchange="setMenuValue(this)">
  <option selected value="9999">Phonetics</option>
  <option value="alpha">Alpha</option>
  <option value="bravo">Bravo</option>
  <option value="charlie">Charlie</option>
</select>
<select id="MenuThree" class="TestMenu" onchange="setMenuValue(this)">
  <option selected value="9999">RGB</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>
<select id="MenuFour" class="TestMenu" onchange="setMenuValue(this)">
  <option selected value="9999">Pets</option>
  <option value="cat">Cat</option>
  <option value="dog">Dog</option>
  <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
</select>
<div id="label"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I used your "this" solution for the error I asked about. And I've used a different fix for the other problem that people have commented on.